# close button with overlay using pseudoelements

Tags: css

I have the following close button with overlay behind it (see image attached). How do I code the button using CSS and pseudo elements?

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="close"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.close {
    position: relative;
    background: url('../images/close.svg');
    background-size: 23px 23px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 100;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.9;

    &:hover {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
}
```

I don't want to have an inner and outer div. I just want one element and use pseudo elements (before or after) to add the overlay behind the close button.

How can I do that using pseudo elements?

[image]

Comment: How can an overlay be behind something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code will look like using a single div and a `::before` pseudo element. More information on pseudo elements can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="close"></div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.close {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;

    /* Pseudo Element */
    &::before {
      content: ''; /* set content to empty */
      display: block; /* display is inline by default */
      position: relative;
      background: url('../images/close.svg');
      background-size: 23px 23px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
      width: 46px;
      height: 46px;
      z-index: 100;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0.9;
    }

    &:hover {
      &::before {
        opacity: 1.0;
      }
    }
}
```